# Using regexp exclude lines that match condition

Tags: regex

I'd like to use regexp to exclude the lines with address 10.0.0.2 from the output below.

My command:

```
cat /var/log/secure | egrep '\s+sshd\[[[:digit:]]+\]: Failed password for (invalid user )?nessus from \S+'
```

Output:

```
Aug 28 09:58:18 server34 sshd[13567]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.4 port 33254 ssh2
Aug 28 09:58:57 server34 sshd[13577]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.4 port 33366 ssh2
Aug 28 10:01:09 server34 sshd[13854]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.4 port 33841 ssh2
Aug 28 10:01:30 server34 sshd[13932]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.4 port 34074 ssh2
Aug 28 10:01:48 server34 sshd[13957]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.4 port 36108 ssh2
Aug 28 10:01:50 server34 sshd[13959]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.4 port 36540 ssh2
Aug 29 03:29:11 server34 sshd[7461]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.2 port 46375 ssh2
Aug 29 03:29:54 server34 sshd[7475]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.2 port 34047 ssh2
Aug 29 03:31:51 server34 sshd[8335]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.2 port 47509 ssh2
Aug 29 03:31:58 server34 sshd[8355]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.2 port 48692 ssh2
Aug 29 03:32:42 server34 sshd[8423]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.2 port 54580 ssh2
Aug 29 03:32:49 server34 sshd[8425]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.2 port 55557 ssh2
```

I'd like to stick with using regexp (in the current format) because that's what SCOM uses when it [scans log files](http://mpwiki.viacode.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=117008) in Linux.

Comment: could you post the input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove useless `cat` and use another `grep -v` for exclusion:

```
egrep '\s+sshd\[[[:digit:]]+\]: Failed password for (invalid user )?nessus from' /var/log/secure | \
 grep -F -v '10.0.0.2'
```

To do that using single `grep`:

```
grep -P '(?!.*?10\.0\.0\.2)\s+sshd\[[[:digit:]]+\]: Failed password for (invalid user )?nessus from \S+' file

Aug 28 09:58:18 server34 sshd[13567]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.4 port 33254 ssh2
Aug 28 09:58:57 server34 sshd[13577]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.4 port 33366 ssh2
Aug 28 10:01:09 server34 sshd[13854]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.4 port 33841 ssh2
Aug 28 10:01:30 server34 sshd[13932]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.4 port 34074 ssh2
Aug 28 10:01:48 server34 sshd[13957]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.4 port 36108 ssh2
Aug 28 10:01:50 server34 sshd[13959]: Failed password for invalid user nessus from 10.0.0.4 port 36540 ssh2
```

Comment: The cat is simply a way to do the regexp in bash for demo.  I'm after a regexp syntax to exclude 10.0.0.2.

Comment: No issue, my answer i.e. `grep -F -v '10.0.0.2'` OR `grep -v '10\.0\.0\.2'` both will work.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm not being clear.  I need to be able to arrive at the output without using grep.  Some how I need the exclusion to be within:
`\s+sshd\[[[:digit:]]+\]: Failed password for (invalid user )?nessus from \S+`

Comment: Can you explain your requirement clearly on why you cannot use `grep -v`?

Comment: SCOM (MS System Center Operations Manager) parses /var/log/secure using the above regexp to look for failed login attempts.  I want to exclude 10.0.0.2 from the output because it's a known machine scanning for vulnerabilities.  So I want to avoid false alerts generated by SCOM.

Comment: yes I understood that but why you cannot use `| grep -F -v '10.0.0.2'` ?

Comment: Oh now you're talking!  I think this is going to work for me.  Testing now.